# Excel - power query (or anything else) - join on partial match between fields?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql, power-query

In power query ([or MS query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39045415/4106771), or really anything else that would create a refresh-able table that gives me the desired results in excel), ***how can I join on partial matches between two fields?***

I want to do something similar to this SQL statement:

```
SELECT T1.SIZES AS SIZES,
       T2.PARTNO as PARTNO
FROM TABLE1 AS T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 AS T2
ON T2.APPLICATIONS LIKE '% ' T1.SIZES ' %'
```

---

For example:  say I have `TABLE1` which has the following data in field `SIZES`

- ***SIZES***
- P01
- P02
- P03
- P04

And I have `TABLE2`, which has the following data in fields `PART NO` and `APPLICATIONS`

- ***PARTNO***__________***APPLICATIONS***
- 11111______________P01/P02
- 22222______________P02/P04
- 33333______________P01/P04

I want to do a left outer join of TABLE 1 on TABLE2, and return any rows which have a partial match between `TABLE1.SIZES` and `TABLE2.APPLICATIONS`. 
The results would be the following:

- ***SIZES***___________***PART NO***
- P01______________11111
- P01______________33333
- P02______________11111
- P02______________22222
- P03______________*null*
- P04______________22222
- P04______________33333

---

I tried to follow along this example of [implementing a like function in power query](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/05/27/implementing-a-basic-likewildcard-search-function-in-power-query/), and was able to create the formula, but can't figure out how to use it as criteria for a "query merge" (join).

I'm a total novice in power query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use a Function for this, I prefer solutions with minimal/no code as they are easier to test and maintain.

I would start with 2 queries, for TABLE1 and TABLE2.  I would use the Add Column / Add Custom Column button on each to add a column.  I would call it **Dummy Match Key** and set the formula as

```
= 1
```

Now back on the TABLE1 query, I would add a Merge step and join to TABLE2, using the **Dummy Match Key**, then Expand the original columns from TABLE2.  Now you have a monster cross-join of every row from TABLE1 vs every row from TABLE2.  Don't panic.  Even at scale PQ handles this scenario well, better IMO than SQL or specialist ETL tools which tend to need huge amounts of memory.

Anyway, next I would use Add Columns / Add Conditional Column and specify:

New Column Name:  Matched Row

If (column) APPLICATIONS contains (column) SIZES then (value) Yes

This will give you a column with a value of "Yes" in only the matched rows.  Filter for those values and remove any columns you don't want and you are done.

Total lines of code = 0.

Comment: Sorry it took 4 years to accept this as the answer, I must have missed the notification that is was answered way back when.  Anyways, this is a pretty good solution in PQ (I haven't tested it, but I've got a lot more experience with PQ now and confident this is a good solution).